# Application Request Routing Client Affinity Server Hash

Tags: iis, hash, affinity, arr

Is it possible to calculate ARR affinity server hash by code? I want to manually set client affinity cookie based on complex rules implemented in a custom managed HTTP module. The only obstacle I have now is how to get all the server hashes in the web farm. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: ARR uses a cookie to achieve client affinity or "session sticky". If a request is with a valid content server hash in cookie, ARR will always honor it and send the request to the corresponding content server regardless of the load balancing algorithm. Normally, a content server hash is calculated by the ARR and sent to the client in the "Set-Cookie" header of the response for the client's first request. My goal is to implement my own client affinity based on rules implemented in a HTTP module. The difficulty is how to get all the server hashes, so that I can manually set cookie.